# Accessing value in sub nested object in JSON with Angular

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm trying access values in sub array objects of results:

```
results: [
{
    list_name: "E-Book Fiction",
    display_name: "E-Book Fiction",
    bestsellers_date: "2016-09-03",
    published_date: "2016-09-18",
    rank: 1,
    rank_last_week: 0,
    weeks_on_list: 1,
    asterisk: 0,
    dagger: 0,
    amazon_product_url: "http://www.amazon.com/Great-Reckoning-Novel-Inspector-Gamache/dp/1250022134?tag=thenewyorktim-20",
isbns: [],
    book_details: [
    {
        title: "A GREAT RECKONING",
        description: "An instructor at the police academy is found murdered, perhaps by one of the cadets favored by Armand Gamache, the retired homicide chief of the Sûreté du Québec.",
        contributor: "by Louise Penny",
        author: "Louise Penny",
        contributor_note: "",
        price: 0,
        age_group: "",
        publisher: "Minotaur",
        primary_isbn13: "9781250022127",
        primary_isbn10: "1250022126"
    }
    ],
    reviews: [
    {
        book_review_link: "",
        first_chapter_link: "",
        sunday_review_link: "",
        article_chapter_link: ""
    }
]
}
```

so that I can grab values like `title` from `book_details`, but currently only able to display the whole response with:

```
<article class="search-result row" ng-repeat="books in results">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
            {{books}}
        </div>
</article>
```

My controller is fairly simple, just grabbing the result:

```
myBooks.controller('bookController', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get("data-url")
    .success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $scope.results = response;
    });
});
```

A screenshot of the object in web console:

[image]

Comment: iterate over book details not on results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write it like this . Create a new books array in the scope by iterating over the results array.

```
app.controller("MyController", ["$scope","$http",
function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.books;

         $http.get('test.json').then(function (response){
              console.log(response.data.results);
             $scope.results = response.data.results;
             $scope.results.map(function(obj, index) {
               if(obj.book_details) {
                 if(!($scope.books)) {
                   $scope.books = [];
                 }
                 for(var i in obj.book_details) {
                  $scope.books.push(obj.book_details[i]);
                 }
               }
             });

             console.log($scope.books);
    });                

}]);

<article class="search-result row" ng-repeat="book in ">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        {{book.title}}
    </div>
</article>
```

[Working link](https://plnkr.co/edit/BQmy7jnpPkHkmx5wN3Et?p=preview)

Comment: That doesn't have any affect.

Comment: I should be able to output Title: A Great Reckoning. I've attached a screenshot of the object in my web console to the question.

Comment: From your response , results is an array , will it have multiple elements in that array

Comment: The problem with this is that you can only grab the first book title. I need to be able to iterate over each object in the results array, and the book_details sub array and grab each title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123196/discussion-between-sasank-sunkavalli-and-user3438917).